# ListView in Relative Layout below and above some layout not fit as wrap content in Dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I have one issue with ListView in Dialog

In the Relative Layout I have one layout at top (Title-alignParentTop), another layout at bottom (Dismiss and Done button-alignParentBottom) and ListView above Dissmiss and Done Button and below title.
ListView can contain one, two or many items, Now according to ListView items my Dialog height is set accordingly but It keep space between last item of listview and bottom bar (when one and two items in the list)

For three and more item it looks good

any solution for this issue ?

My xml file is listed below.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@+id/root"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:background="@color/transparent"
> android:orientation="vertical"
> android:paddingBottom="20dp"
> android:paddingTop="20dp">
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="@color/white"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:paddingTop="10dp">
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/linear_middle"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:focusable="true"
>         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:padding="@dimen/menuLstPad"
>             android:text="@string/lbl_rate_order"
>             android:textColor="@color/black"
>             android:textSize="20sp" />
>         <View
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="0.5dp"
>             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>             android:background="#DBDBDB" />
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <ListView
>         android:id="@+id/lv_data"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/ll_bottom"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/linear_middle"
>         android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
>     </ListView>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:gravity="bottom"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:padding="10dp">
>         <View
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="0.5dp"
>             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>             android:background="#DBDBDB" />
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="horizontal">
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_dismiss"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_weight="1"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:padding="10dp"
>                 android:text="DISMISS"
>                 android:textColor="#242424"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_done"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_weight="1"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:padding="10dp"
>                 android:text="DONE"
>                 android:textColor="#242424"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </RelativeLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As You are using Relative layout and assign bottom bar `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` which make the relative layout to spread as the screen size available. 
RelativeLayout Ignore all bounds if you align anything on its bottom.
For above layout you have to either remove Relative layout and start using LinearLayout as your all views are in vertical order.

Comment: But My requirement is that The Top bar (Title) and Bottom Bar should be there in Dialog , but dialog height should be render according to listview items, If I take Linear layout Dismiss and Done Button goes to end of the ListView, but not display at bottom always

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/menuLstPad"
        android:text="@string/lbl_rate_order"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#DBDBDB" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_middle"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#DBDBDB" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_dismiss"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="DISMISS"
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_done"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="DONE"
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Sorry, It will not full fill my requirement as I need Dismiss and Done button as always display bottom and ListView in between Top Bar (Title) and Bottom Bar (Dismiss and Done Button)

Comment: Did u try that layout, it is exactly what you needed